# Запуск телеграмм бота по крону

Tags: php, ооп, telegram-bot

Здраствуйте, мой бот срабатывает когда на него стучится webhook телеграмма и запускается следующим кодом

```
//Load composer
require 'путь/vendor/autoload.php';
use Longman\TelegramBot\Request;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram;


$API_KEY = 'key';
$BOT_NAME = 'bot';
$mysql_credentials = [
   'host'     => '321',
   'user'     => '123',
   'password' => '321',
   'database' => '123',
];


$telegram = new Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram($API_KEY, $BOT_NAME);

$telegram->enableMySQL($mysql_credentials);
$telegram->enableMySQL($mysql_credentials, $BOT_NAME . '_');

$commands_path = ['путь1/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/examples/Commands/',
                    'путь2/Commands/'];



$telegram->addCommandsPaths($commands_path);
$telegram->enableAdmin(12345);
$telegram->setDownloadPath(__DIR__ .'/Download');
$telegram->setUploadPath(__DIR__ .'/Upload');
$handle = $telegram->handle();
```

Встал вопрос, как запустить бота по крону? мне нужно взять из базы ид чата и отправить туда сообщение. Не понимаю как это сделать используя ооп

Есть переменная $chat_id и $text, как их передать на выполнение?

Comment: а почему именно ООП?

Comment: так а как еще? заново переписывать обращение к апи телеграмма? явно же есть возможность запустить этот код без этого

Comment: можно и в императивном стиле это сделать

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не совсем понимаю

Comment: Задачу формализуйте. Что значит отправить сообщение? Вы хотите их задать фиксированные в самом крон-файле? Но тогда вопрос сводится к парсингу аргументов командной строки в php, не более Касательно крона все просто. Вызываете crontab -e пишете время выполнения скрипта и путь к нему. Получается строчка вроде `3 * * * * * /usr/bin/php path_to_my_script.php arg0 arg1`

Comment: @gecube, спасибо. нашел решение. ниже в моем ответе. мне нужен был код. Вопрос был в том что бы инициировать работу бота без события (в моем случае запроса webhook), при помощи крона по некоторым условиям

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за обсуждения, сам поковырял доки по пхп и php-телеграмм-боту
и понял что статический метод можно запустить из любого куска кода

собственно вот решение, может кому то понадобится

```
<?php
// Load composer
require 'путь/vendor/autoload.php';
use Longman\TelegramBot\Request;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram;

//тут ваш код

$data['chat_id'] = '123456';
$data['text'] = 'я месага';
$result = Request::sendMessage($data);
```